# global Dto for ID

Tags: nestjs, query-string, dto

I have a project by NEST.JS , i want to have a global Dto for validate ID structure that client sends in Param in various routes.

my common Dto for ID is:

```
export class IdDto {
  @IsString()
  @Length(36)
  groupId: string;
}
```

i want to use this common validation for various Params in various routes, like these:

ROUTE 1):

```
 @Get('/public/subgroup/:subgroupId/auction')
  async getProductsByFilter(@Param() subgroupId: IdDto, @Query() 
    queryObject:any):Promise<any> {
    return this.productService.getProductsByFilter(subgroupId, queryObject);
  }
```

ROUTE 2):

```
  @Put('/envoy/product/:productId')
   async update(@Param() productId:IdDto, @Headers() headers: any ): Promise<any> {
    let payLoad = await headerToPayload(headers);
    return await this.productService.update(productId,payLoad);
   }
```

MY PROBLEM IS:

When each of routes, receive it's Param, it compares with name of Param by IdDto.
and it did not passes validation.

in ROUTE 1, it validates `{subgroupId: 'values' }` by `IdDto`.

in ROUTE 2, IT validates `{ productId: 'value'}` by `IdDto`.

that `IdDto` is in form of `{groupId: 'value'}`, that as a result, this validation, could not pass!

my problem is this:
HOW CAN I GLOBALISE THIS `IdDto` for every routes?

Comment: How important for you to have different route parameter variable names in each controller? This looks like unnecessary workload because without different id names in each controller you can use single DTO.

Comment: this difference for ID names are essential for Routes in project.

Comment: Can you maybe explain why it's essential? Why would `/envoy/product/:id` and `/public/subgroup/:id/auction` not be valid routes for you?